# How to bypass 'swipe to unlock' screen

Tags: android, fingerprint, lockscreen

I am implementing a custom 'swipe to unlock' screen.

If the 'Screen lock' in settings is 'Swipe', my app work properly.
In my custom 'swipe to unlock' screen -> User swipe to unlock -> it unlocks phone and go to home screen directly by adding the code below in my activity:

`activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD); activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);`

The problem arises when the 'Screen lock' in settings is 'PIN', the code above does not affect. What I expect is it will bypass the default 'swipe to unlock' screen and go to 'PIN input' screen, so users don't have to swipe twice to enter their PIN.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that we cannot avoid the default 'swipe to unlock' screen, so I try with another approach that using finger print.

`@Override public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) { mCallback.onAuthenticated(); }`

Currently, I have to touch to the sensor twice, first to dismiss my lock screen and second for the default lock screen. The [next app](https://www.apk4fun.com/apk/24135/) can dismiss 2 lock screen with only one touch, so I think it is possible to do so.

Comment: Be a Vendor / System app.

Comment: You cann't without System Permissions, because next swipe to unlock (with pin), based on System, and on some other device, there willn't be seconds screen, but just PIN.

Comment: @GensaGames it means it is impossible with unrooted devices?

Comment: After looking at how gravitybox does it, I've come to the conclusion that there is in fact no way to achieve this without root. Reference https://github.com/GravityBox/GravityBox/blob/marshmallow/src/com/ceco/marshmallow/gravitybox/ModLockscreen.java with settings key PREF_KEY_LOCKSCREEN_DIRECT_UNLOCK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t need to listen to finger print, just register when device is unlocked and dismiss your lock screen:

```
void registerUnlockReceiver() {
    IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    registerReceiver(mUserUnlockedReceiver , i);
}

BroadcastReceiver mUserUnlockedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        unlockAndExit(false);
    }
};
```